# How to integrate website with Flickr Api

Tags: php, api, flickr

I would like to integrate my website with Flickr API. I have already generate oauth_token and oauth_token_secret but I don`t know what to do next, how to use them for getting user photos.

Thx in advance

I am using http://sourceforge.net/projects/phlickr/ class to work with it:

```
$flickr = new Flickr($this->FLICKR_CONSUMER_KEY, $this->FLICKR_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$flickr->authenticate('read');

$oauth_token = $flickr->getOauthData(Flickr::OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN);
$oauth_token_secret = $flickr->getOauthData(Flickr::OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

Comment: Aren't you better off reading up on Flickr's documentation for the API?

Comment: I have already done it

Answer (score 2):

> I am using http://sourceforge.net/projects/phlickr/ class to work with it:

I don't think you are. From what I can tell, Phlickr is no longer being actively developed and doesn't support OAuth. Also it's use is nothing like the code you show.

Based on the tiny code snippet you provide, I think you are actually using my [DPZFlickr](https://github.com/dopiaza/DPZFlickr) library.

If that is the case, then you should find some sample code in the examples directory that does what you are looking for. Essentially, you need to do something like this:

```
$flickr = new Flickr($this->FLICKR_CONSUMER_KEY, $this->FLICKR_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$flickr->authenticate('read');
$parameters =  array(
    'user_id' => '50317659@N00',  // Replace with the NSID of the user you are interested in
    'per_page' => 100,
    'extras' => 'url_sq,path_alias',
    );

$response = $flickr->call('flickr.photos.search', $parameters);
$photos = $response['photos'];
```

$photos will then contain an array of photos. Again, the examples will show you code that takes that data and generates HTML from it.